# Bug in new highcharts renderer?

Tags: highcharts

The following jsfiddle shows an example where I'm placing text on the chart, getting the width/height of that text, then using the width/height to work out where to place the same text again, but this time in the middle of the chart, and with a bounding box around it:

http://jsfiddle.net/drmrbrewer/mfr0rd4b/3/

The above is using highcharts 4.0.4.

```
some code
```

Here is the exact same code, but using highcharts 4.1.1:

http://jsfiddle.net/drmrbrewer/mfr0rd4b/4/

The bounding box has been placed around the first-placed text, despite using the x,y,width,height information from the second-placed text to create the bounding box.

Is this a bug in the new version?

Is there a better way to work out place text, with a bounding box, bang in the middle of a chart?  Till now, I've been placing (invisible) dummy text, using width/height of that to work out where to place the real text, then adding the bounding box.  Which is why I've run into this issue in the new version.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm still not sure why the example in the OP broke going from 4.0.4 to 4.1.1, but a partial answer to my question, which at least provides a solution that works even in 4.1.1, is given by the following jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/drmrbrewer/mfr0rd4b/7/

```
    text = chart.renderer.text("My Text").add();
    textBBox = text.getBBox();
    x = chart.plotLeft + (chart.plotWidth * 0.5) - (textBBox.width * 0.5);
    y = chart.plotTop  + (chart.plotHeight * 0.5) - (textBBox.height * 0.25);
    text.attr({x: x, y: y, zIndex: 10});

    rect = chart.renderer.rect(x, y, textBBox.width, textBBox.height, 2)
        .attr({
            fill: '#FFFFEF',
            stroke: 'gray',
            'stroke-width': 1,
            zIndex: 9
        })
        .add();
    rectBBox = rect.getBBox();
    rect.attr({y: y - rectBBox.height*0.5 - textBBox.height*0.25});
```

A second mystery is why it's `textBBox.height * 0.25` and not `textBBox.height * 0.5`...

EDIT... dang!  The new solution breaks when I add a `<br>` to split the text across lines:

http://jsfiddle.net/drmrbrewer/mfr0rd4b/8/

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I would just try to use `renderer.label` instead of `renderer.text`: http://jsfiddle.net/mfr0rd4b/10/ I'm a bit confused - why do you need to update rect position using it's bounding box? Anyway, what are you really trying to achieve? Regarding `label` -> it can include background/box/borders/shadows etc: http://jsfiddle.net/mfr0rd4b/12/

Comment: I love highcharts... whatever the problem, there's always a solution!  Looks like labels are the way to go, with integrated bounding box options, and ability to use <br> without issues.  The reason for updating the position based on the bounding box is that just placing a label based on plotWidth/2 and plotHeight/2 is that it will place the *corner* in the middle.  To get the label truly centred, you need to know its width and height, and shift it based on half of those.  BTW, why is it `textBBox.height * 0.25` and not `textBBox.height * 0.5` for that purpose?

Comment: And, any way of having better control over padding... I find that the padding is not even around the label, e.g. see http://jsfiddle.net/drmrbrewer/mfr0rd4b/13/ .  Also, any way to add a corner radius to the label bounding box?

Comment: Because you can set `align: 'center'`: http://jsfiddle.net/mfr0rd4b/14/ :) Or use `anchorX`/`Y`. Regarding radius - that's hard one, because background is rendered as path, not as rect. `callout` shape has support partially for border radius: http://jsfiddle.net/mfr0rd4b/15/ (it comes from the tooltip.shape). Regarding padding - isn't that caused by setting baseline?

Comment: `align: 'center'` only centres horizontally, not vertically?  Where do I find a reference for how to use `anchorX`/`Y`?  And how do I set baseline to avoid non-uniform padding as seen in the jsfiddle example?  (using `callout` shape to get the radius is just fine, thanks)

Comment: To find docs, see sources. Unfortunately `label` isn't officially in the API. And you are right, since you need vertical middle position, then you need bounding box. I can see 1px problemwith padding here: http://jsfiddle.net/mfr0rd4b/16/ - I guess rounding problems, though.

Comment: OK, always slightly nervous about using something (label) that isn't officially in the API, because support for it is more likely to be dropped or its behaviour changed.  And do you have any comment on the original post, where I give two identical jsfiddles, the only diffference being 4.0.4 vs 4.1.1... it doesn't seem correct to me that -- with 4.1.1 -- the bounding box of boxA is being used when drawing the rect, even though I've referenced boxB.  Seems like a bug.  I had this "draw text centrally" working just fine, and it broke going from 4.0.4 to 4.1.1 for this reason.

Comment: And, when shifting the label/text by half of the width and height to centralise it, why does `textBBox.width * 0.5` work, but for height it's `textBBox.height * 0.25`??

Comment: Regarding initial issue - it's cased by caching - you can clear local cache this way: `chart.renderer.cache = [];` , demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mfr0rd4b/18/ Or, when getting bounding box, use `getBBox(true)` to not using cached values: http://jsfiddle.net/mfr0rd4b/19/. And this will only happen, when you have two exactly the same texts on the chart. Regarding `height * 0.25` -> could you show me demo once again?

Comment: And it seems like more than just a 1px problem with padding here: jsfiddle.net/mfr0rd4b/16 -- the padding at the bottom is a *lot* bigger than the padding at the top.

Comment: I think it's 1px -> try to highlight element in the dev tools.

Comment: regarding, see `height * 0.25`, see [link](http://jsfiddle.net/drmrbrewer/mfr0rd4b/20/) -- try changing 0.25 to 0.5.  And I'd be interested to know whether you have a simple way of getting the bounding box to fit around the text, as intended, in this jsfiddle example (other than by using labels instead!)

Comment: It's caused by using multiple lines, as you noticed. It's not 0.25 nor 0.5 - it depends on fontSize for the line. In your case it's always 15px. You can get offset this way: http://jsfiddle.net/mfr0rd4b/22/. It still looks a bit off, but when you compare elements in the DOM values are the correct ones, though..

Comment: Thanks -- there's absolutely no way I would have got to the same point without your help!

Comment: As ever, there's a complication.  I'm actually doing the rendering on a server, using phantomjs.  The `tspan = text.element.children[0]` and `offset = chart.renderer.fontMetrics` thing doesn't seem to work in that environment?  Is it for a browser environment only?  Any workaround?

Comment: Make sure you have up-to-date server and highcharts.js on the server.  Default exporting server works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/mfr0rd4b/23/ ?